# JavaScript Logout Function (PhoneGap Mobile Development)

Tags: javascript, phonegap

I am a newbie to coding and I am coming across an issue with my logout function which I have pasted below.

```js
function logout()
{
  localStorage.setItem("data", data);
  var user = localStorage.getItem("data");
  user.rows.item(0).name;
  localStorage.removeItem("data");
  window.location.href = "signin.html";

}
```

I am calling it via this html fuction:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="logout()" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i></span> Logout</a>
```

What I am trying to do is when the user clicks on the logout button, on click it will invoke a function in which it will remove the data of the user from the local storage and direct them back to the sign in page.

I'm not sure where I have gone wrong here. I'd like to know if I've written it wrong so I can learn from my mistakes and improve on my JavaScript.

Thank you :)

Comment: Well what exactly is the problem? What doesn't work? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: @Pointy ... Hi, the problem is nothing happens. It doesn't even go to the page which I have outlined in the "window.location.href". All that happens is the user is taken to the top of the profile page they are on, which I'm guessing is because of the href="#" in the <a> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#logout").click(function(){
            localStorage.login="false";
            localStorage.removeItem("username");
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        });
});
```

Comment: Well problem was `localStorage.setItem("data", data);`. You do not need to `setItem` again. Item is already set on probably `login`. Good luck! And please accept my answer! :)